# git no reconoce mi usuario, sin importar mi configuración

Tags: git, github, git-push

Hace poco venía trabajando con git desde la terminal de mi macOS Sierra sin problemas. De hecho, pude montar una pagina en gitpages subiéndola al repositorio `usuario.github.io`.

Ahora que intento hacer push con otra cuenta de github, pero desde el mismo computador, github me niega el acceso:

```
$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to gustavoahumada/gustavoahumada.github.io.git denied to jonathanahumada.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/gustavoahumada/gustavoahumada.github.io/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Mi problema se sintetiza en esta linea: `Permission to gustavoahumada/gustavoahumada.github.io.git denied to jonathanahumada.`, ya que el usuario de git no debería mostrar `jonathanahumada` (la cuenta que usaba antes), sino `gustavoahumada`(la cuenta que uso ahora). De hecho, si le pregunto al shell cuál es mi usuario, me retorna efectivamente el segundo caso:

```
$ git config user.name
gustavoahumada
```

Así que no puedo entender por qué cuando hago `git push` aparezco como `jonathanahumada`, si cuando escribo `git config user.name` aparezco como `gustavoahumada`.

He intentado:

1. borrar y generar nuevamente la clave ssh y configurarla en github.com.
2. probar mi conexion ssh, con lo que he tenido éxito.

   $ssh -T git@github.com
   Hi gustavoahumada! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does 
   not provide shell access.'

En suma, no entiendo por qué github me reconoce como jonathanahumada cuando hago push y me niega el acceso, mientras que si pruebo mi conexión y configuración me retorna otro valor.

Comment: los comandos de `git config` los corres desde la carpeta del proyecto?

Comment: @Daniel Pérez, sí. Lo hago desde el directorio del proyecto y, por ejemplo, el user.name y el user.email quedan configurados. Lo raro es que no carga esa configuracion especificamente con el 'push'.

Comment: @JackNavaRow. No estoy seguro en cuanto a los permisos, ni sé cómo chequearlos. Como ves, apenas estoy aprendiendo a utilizar git. Solo sé que es un repositorio publico y que le he registrado una clave ssh.

Comment: trata de usar en la consola con permisos root, si se te hace muy dificil la consola.. descarga SourceTree

Comment: tengo el mismo problema. Te referís a que borraste todo el historial de contraseñas de tu navegador?. Ya lo hice y me sigue pasando lo mismo, tengo Windows.

Comment: @Paula, este problema fue de hace un año así que no recuerdo bien los detalles. No obstante, recuerdo que el problema fue con el llavero de MacOS (Keychain). Esto es diferente al historial de contraseñas del navegador, ya que este  guarda en general todas las contraseñas que usas en el sistema operativo. Tal vez Windows tenga algo similar, pero no estoy familiarizado. Espero que puedas solucionar tu problema.

Comment: modifica el `.gitconfig`y agrega el nuevo usuario

Answer (score 3):

He solucionado el problema. Me metí en el Keychain Access del mac y borré todos los registros relacionados con Github, a pesar de que en principio solo eran los passwords almacenados en el navegador.

Luego de hacer esto, la terminal me solicitó nombre de usuario y contraseña al hacer el push.

Aun no sé porque los datos del Keychain sobreescriben la configuracion del .gitconfig o el ssh-agent, así que cualquier comentario iluminador es bienvenido.

Gracias,

Answer (score 2):

Tenia el mismo problema en Windows y ya que vi que se soluciona borrando las credenciales, busque la forma de hacer los mismo en Windows y si resultó.

Les indico como hacerlo :

1. Me voy a inicio
2. En el buscador coloco Administrador de Credenciales
3. Entro al Administrador de Credenciales
4. Me ubico a Credenciales Genéricas
5. Busco la credencial que es de github y le ordeno quitar del almacén
6. Y listo ya cuando hagan el push a su repositorio en github les volverá a pedir su usuario y contraseña

Nota: También pueden entrar al Administrador de Credenciales desde Panel de Control/Cuentas de Usuario y Protección Infantil/Administrador de Credenciales

Answer (score 0):

yo tenia el mismo problema probe de muchisimás formas pero ningúna me funcionaba.

Hasta que un día descargue Github Desktop, lo instale, hice todo el proceso de autentificación. Volvi a realizar el push al repositorio y en vez de pedirme el token lo que hice fue pedirme autentificación mediante el Github Desktop y listo. Fue todo espero te sirva.